# What are all possible values that can be passed for "scope" in box content API auth?

Tags: api, box

Box documentation at https://developers.box.com/docs/#oauth-2, says that user is redirected to authentication page in first leg of oAuth, and application can pass a parameter "scope".

> **scope**: What scope the eventual auth token will have. This field is not required. If not specified the application will get the default scope configured. If your application has different kinds of users that may need different types of scope, then you can provide a comma separated list of scopes, to give some users a lower scope if they sign in from different locations. If you are using a Provision-granted application, you must specify the alias: folder_readwrite to use the auth-code grant.
>   Type: string

But I could not find what are all possible values that can be passed as scope.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

My requirement is to restrict the login to only box admins, if someone has any other ideas then please share.

Answer (score 2):

If you still need help with this, to see all the possible values, check all the scopes in your app (actually select the all the checkboxes). Then, in your initial request to Box (i.e. https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize) do not include a scope parameter. You will be redirected to a Box authorize page (login if necessary). There should be a hidden input with all the possible scope values.

From my scope settings I received this hidden input

`name="scope" value="root_readwrite manage_enterprise manage_managed_users manage_groups manage_enterprise_properties"`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Box.com still have this hidden input with scopes inside the User login page

Answer (score 0):

Using [beast's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39604301/67824) I was able to find the appropriate documentation page:
https://developer.box.com/v2.0/docs/authentication#section-oauth-2-scopes

Here's what it says at the time of writing:

- `root_readwrite` - Read and write all files and folders
- `manage_enterprise` - Manage an enterprise
- `manage_managed_users` - Manage an enterprise's managed users
- `manage_groups` - Manage an enterprise's groups
- `manage_enterprise_properties` - Manage an enterprise's properties
- `manage_data_retention` - Manage an enterprise's retention policies
- `manage_app_users` - Create and manage app users
- `manage_webhook` - Manage Webhooks

They also have a few scopes that require filing a support ticket (no OAuth2 name provided):

- `Global Content Manager`
- `Admin can make calls on behalf of Users`
- `Can suppress email notifications from API calls`